# Is there a way to shorten the input command for specific classes in my package?

Tags: python, import

I would like to create a package that has roughly this structure:

```
package
    contrib
        case1
            src
                __init__.py
                case1.py
                    class case1
                    + other functions
            data

        case2
            src
                __init__.py
                case2.py
                    class case2
                    + other functions
            data

        case3
        ...
```

The user will get access to `caseX` by accessing `class caseX` in the `caseX` subfolder.

I went with this format to make it simple for others to contribute their own cases. The idea is that a contributors can, one day, add their own cases by creating a new `caseY` subfolder in the `contrib` folder.

However, this structure makes the import command for the classes very long. It would be something like this:

`from package.contrib.case1.src.case1 import case1`

My question is: Is there a way to shorten the import command? Ideally, I would want to import the `class caseX' from the` classX` subfolder by simply writing this:

`from package import case1`

Is that possible?

Comment: you can create __init__ at package level and import your requirements with non conflicting alias names in __init__ file then you can use from package import your_alias_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is also having these issues, I figured it out using the importlib package. In the directory `/package/contrib/` I added the following to `__init__.py`:

```
import importlib

# Add one of these for each class I want to directly load using import
case1 = getattr(importlib.import_module("case1.src.case1", package='package'), "case1")
```

`case1.src.case1` is the path to the file `case1.py` in Python "dot" notation. The last bit (`... , "case1")`) refers to the `class case1` in the file `case1.py`.

Now I can write this command and get direct access to the class:

`from package import case1`